# Wifi keep disconnecting every 5 min on Dell Inspiron15r

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, dell

Need urgent help, I am new to Ubuntu and using 12.04.
My Wifi keep disconnecting after a while when i start my machine, i always need to restart the system to get connected and again it gets disconnected in 2 min.
Sometime when i restart it shows no wifi availability and the after few trials of restarting, it fortunately gets connected. It happened not only @ my home but at my college as well. Its damn irritating that when i am writing an email and suddenly the wifi get disconnect.
I am using Dell Inspiron 15r. Please help me out. 
I googled it a lot but could not find a solution, i read a solution of reversing the IP but i didnt get what and How to do it.

Comment: This is likely due to your network card - it could be that the wrong driver is being used, causing unpredictable behaviour. Could you please edit the question to include the output of the following commands, run from the terminal:

`sudo lshw -c network`

`nm-tool`

Answer (score 1):

That happens to me, but I don't get it often. Just click on the wifi icon at the top left side of the gray bar. Click on disconnect then connect to the desired wifi. It usually works.

Comment: For me it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your network card is plugged in to the expansion slot on the motherboard properly. You may have jostled it at some point and loosened it.